# Lookup data using ruby and execute bash with data

Tags: ruby, bash, lookup

What I want to do is to use Siriproxy to control my Sky+ box (which I have working to a degree)

Sky uses channel numbers but converts them to hex numbers that it understands. I have the file with all channel numbers, the channel names and the hex codes. I want to make a ruby script that looks up the hex of the channel number I say and then send it as part of a command to the sky box through a bash script (unless there is an easier way).

I currently have a very crude and long winded way of doing it that involves multiple bash scripts creating .txt files etc but I'm sure there must be a better way.

EDIT with more info:

```
#demonstrate capturing data from the user (e.x. "Siri proxy number 15")
listen_for /change the channel number ([0-9,]*[0-9])/i do |number|
#say "Changing the Channel to #{number}"
f = File.new("/root/SiriProxy/sky/channel.txt", "w")
f.puts "SKY#{number}"
f.close
#system("echo [Info - Plugin Manager] Channel number #{number} stored to sky/channel.txt")
system("sh /root/SiriProxy/sky/change_channel.sh")
File.open('/root/SiriProxy/sky/channel_name.txt').each_line{ |s|
#puts s
say "I've changed the channel to #{s}"
}
request_completed
end
```

Then there is the bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for line in `cat /root/SiriProxy/sky/channel.txt`
do
cat /root/SiriProxy/sky/channel_numbers.txt | grep $line | cut -d"  " -f3 > /root/SiriProxy/sky/hex.txt
done

for line in `cat /root/SiriProxy/sky/channel.txt`
do
cat /root/SiriProxy/sky/channel_numbers.txt | grep $line | cut -d"  " -f2 > /root/SiriProxy/sky/channel_name.txt
done

for line in `cat /root/SiriProxy/sky/hex.txt`
do
(echo 'POST /SkyPlay HTTP/1.1
SOAPACTION: "urn:schemas-nds-com:service:SkyPlay:2#SetAVTransportURI"
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 399 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><s:Envelope s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><u:SetAVTransportURI xmlns:u="urn:schemas-nds-com:service:SkyPlay:2"><InstanceID>0</InstanceID><CurrentURI>xsi://'$line'</CurrentURI><CurrentURIMetaData>NOT_IMPLEMENTED</CurrentURIMetaData></u:SetAVTransportURI></s:Body></s:Envelope>') | nc -n 192.168.1.82 49153
done
```

Thanks for any help, this is a little above my novice status!

Comment: Provide sample of the file, the way you communicate with the box, etc. Also, do you have a *specific* question? This is not a write-teh-code-plz forum.

Comment: Apologies @KarolyHorvath I have added the code I am currently using.

Comment: Could I change the code so I was sending the final SOAP command from Ruby rather than bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I refactored all your file reads from bash script. Please refer `net/http` documentation to send post request.

Here is a snippet. I am not sure whether this works since I don't have those files. But this should give you a fair idea.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'net/http'

channel_numbers_file = '/root/SiriProxy/sky/channel.txt'
listen_for /change the channel number ([0-9,]*[0-9])/i do |number|
  sky_number = "SKY#{number}"
  #Check whether there are multiple occurrences. No idea whether there are multiple occurrences.Gets only 1st one.
  #Remove commma to get all in an array.
  line, = File.open(channel_numbers_file).readlines.select{ |line| line.chomp.include? sky_number } #grep $line part
  hex, channel_name = line.split[1..2] #check indices. ruby indices start from 0.

  #Refer net/http documentation on POST request.
  #send request  
end
```

Not sure if this helped.

Comment: I'd recommend looking at [HTTPClient](https://github.com/nahi/httpclient) for this instead of using Net::HTTP. Net::HTTP is a great building block but would take a lot of code to offer what comes automatically using HTTPClient which has a POST built in.

Comment: It looks great. Am i right in saying this would open the channel number file, search for the number and then take the corresponding hex key? Is it possible to awk out the hex to the bash file in order to execute the SOAP command?

Comment: @user2689371 You can execute bash(your SOAP netcat) code from ruby by wrapping them in `%x[command]`. `HTTPClient` has lots of goodies.